# Function with pointers: Member reference base type (...) is not a structure or union

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, clang

I've the following error:

> "error: member reference base type 'start'
>         (aka 'struct no_start *') is not a structure or union".

So, I have many structures like:

```
typedef struct no_start * start;

struct no_start{
   prog * node_program;
};
```

And functions like this:

```
start * insert_start(prog * program){

   start * data = (start *) malloc(sizeof(start));

   data->node_program = program;

   return data;

}
```

I have a file functions.c where simple functions like this are at, a file structs.h where the structs are and the last functions.h, where i declare my functions of first file.

I dont understand why I'm having this errors. For each function I get as many errors as assigns.

Comment: `data` is a pointer to pointer, write `start data = (start)malloc(...` instead

Comment: in C you don't cast the `malloc`, which language is this?

Comment: if i dont cast it or if i just write start (without "*") i get this 
     
    >"warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'start'
      (aka 'struct no_start *') from a function with result type 'start *' (aka
      'struct no_start **'); take the address with &
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        return data;"

Comment: @miguelpveloso That's because you wrote the wrong return type.

Comment: You mean that i've to return &data?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz, casting the value returned by malloc is a bad habit, but too extended.  I'm afraid this is C.  Also, it's very common to tag as *C* and *C++* questions that only have to do with one of these two different languages.  In addition, **malloc(3)** is a C function (not C++)  It's usable for backwards compatibility with C.  In C++, the use of **malloc(3)** is discouraged (see Stroustrup for a reference) for the more secure operators `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to make a pointer of the struct.

I had `typedef struct no_start * start;`

Instead I needed `typedef struct no_start start;`

Answer (score 1):

Expand the typedef and you'll see what went wrong:

```
struct no_start ** data = (struct no_start **) malloc(sizeof(struct no_start*)); 
data->node_program = program; // Nope; *data is a pointer
```

You could use

```
start data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
data->node_program = program;
```

But it's usually better to avoid "pointer-typedefs", except possibly if they're used for opaque types (i.e. where the struct definition is hidden).

If you dislike typing `struct` everywhere (which is unnecessary in C++), you can typedef the struct:

```
typedef struct no_start no_start;

no_start* insert_start(prog* program){
   no_start* data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
   data->node_program = program;
   return data;
}
```

Of course, in C++ you should use `new`, not `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to type caste the return of malloc. Doing so will create a pointer, to a pointer. Where as a non casted malloc call will return a pointer to the memory allocated for your structure

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do

```
typedef struct no_start * start;
```

ie typedef something as a pointer to a structure without doing

- a typedef of the struct itself
- naming the pointer typedef something like start_ptr

otherwise people get confused. As you did yourself.

```
 start * data = (start *) malloc(sizeof(start));
```

assumes that start is a struct - it isnt. You mean

```
 start  data = malloc(sizeof(struct no_start));
```

better is

```
typedef struct no_start{
   prog * node_program;
} start;

typedef start * start_ptr;

     start_ptr  data = malloc(sizeof(start));
```